# Add data from database in a drop down in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list for cities, and I have cities in my database that I want to populate to a drop down list.

On the Page load made an sql connection

```
 Dim s As String = "Connection String"
 sqlconn = New SqlConnection(s)
```

Now on the drop down load I have a query which is working fine. How to add results from the database query to the drop down?

```
   Protected Sub Citydropdown_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Citydropdown.Load

        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("select City from usrRegister_aunthentication", sqlconn)
        If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then
            sqlconn.Open()
        End If
        Dim i As String = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
            sqlconn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Also, sometimes the same city is repeated. How do I only show each city once?

Comment: Pro tip: you'll get better answers if you put more work into your question. See the edit for what something that's much easier for those of who answer to use.  Also, I hope you pay a **lot** more attention to the details of your code than you did to your question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `ExecuteNonQuery` to fetch the result (rows). Use `ExecuteReader` to obtains the reader instance.

```
Dim dataReader as SqlDataReader 
dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
While dataReader.Read
  ' Write code to insert an Item into dropdownlist
  DropDownItem1.Items.Add(dataReader("City").ToString())
End While
dataReader.Close()
```

Comment: that i have edited  but what code i have to wrtie so as to fill data in the drop -down , which code should e written in while loop?

Comment: and more ova when i use ExecuteReader it says SqldataReader can not  be  convertedt to string

Comment: can i ask u 1 more query ? in the same ques above ?

Comment: @RaghavChopra - Of course but it must be related to this post.

Comment: i am getting vales in ma drop down list
but in my table there are same  entries also for example : suppose there is a city washington in my database table  there  are 2 people from washington  so the drop down is having 2 washington in dropdown infact i want 1 itm for washington in drop down
i hope i made u clear @AVD

Comment: Do you want to fetch distinct city? SELECT DISTINCT CITY from usrRegister_aunthentication

Comment: Now If i wanna Ask Something morE Related To this Post should i have to again post a question

Comment: i wanna active 2nd droopDown  on slecting hte index Of 1st , How can i do that ?

Comment: You should post a question with complete problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this.  It is a line or two less.

```
Using dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
While dr.Read
     ' Write code to insert an Item into dropdownlist
     DropDownItem1.Items.Add(dr("City").ToString())
End While
End Using
```